# the images are displayed in the emulator IOS but not in the real devices

Tags: react-native

in the emulator the images are shown perfectly but when compiling and sending to the store the images of the navigation bar are not displayed correctly

emulator:
the emulator the images are shown perfectly

[image]

device:
on devices the imeges are shown as shown below

[image]

code:

```js
import React from "react";
import {createStackNavigator,DrawerActions} from 'react-navigation';
import {
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
    Platform,
} from "react-native";


import DrawerScreen from './menu/DrawerScreen';
import Load from './screens/Load';
import CacheStore from 'react-native-cache-store';
import ListProduct from './screens/ListProduct';
import Points from './screens/Points';
import OffConnection from './screens/OffConnection';
import CategorieList from './screens/CategorieList';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');

let img = null;
setInterval(()=>{
    CacheStore.get('image').then((value) => {
        if(value === 1 ){
            img = require('../public/images/carShopRed.png');
        }else{
            img = require('../public/images/carShop.png');
        }
    });
},100);


export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
   screen_load:{
       screen:Load,
       navigationOptions:{
           header:null,
           drawerLockMode:'unlocked',
       }
   },
    screen_Off:{
       screen:OffConnection,
       navigationOptions:{
           header:null,
           drawerLockMode:'unlocked',
       }
   },
    screen_List: {
        screen: ListProduct,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            headerLeft:
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate('Points');
                    }}
                >
                    <Image source={require('../public/images/back3.png')}
                           style={{
                               width: 40,
                               height: 35,
                               resizeMode: 'contain',
                               marginBottom:3,
                               marginLeft:4
                           }}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>,
            headerRight: "",
        }),
    },
    screen_Category: {
        screen: CategorieList,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            headerLeft:
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate('Products');
                    }}
                >
                    <Image source={require('../public/images/back3.png')}
                           style={{
                               width: 40,
                               height: 35,
                               resizeMode: 'contain',
                               marginBottom:3,
                               marginLeft:4
                           }}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>,
            headerRight: "",
        }),
    },
    DrawerStack:{screen:DrawerScreen}

}, {
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => (
        {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor:'rgb(70,70,70)',

        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
            ...Platform.select({
                ios:{
                    width: width,

                }
            })

        },
            ...Platform.select({
                ios:{
                    title:
                        <Image source={require('../public/images/banner.png')}
                               style={{
                                   width:width,


                               }}
                        />,
                }
            }),
            ...Platform.select({
                android:{
                    headerBackground: <Image source={require('../public/images/banner.png')}
                                             style={{
                                                 width:width,
                                                 height:56,
                                             }}
                    />,
                }
            }),

        headerTintColor: 'black',
        headerLeftStyle:{
            backgroundColor:'rgb(70,70,70)',
        },
        headerLeft: <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
                }}
            >
                <Image source={require('../public/images/menu.png')}
                       style={{
                           width: 40,
                           height: 40,
                           resizeMode: 'center',
                           position:'relative',
                           marginLeft:10,
                       }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>,
            headerRight:<View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('MyShopping')}
                >
                    <Image source={img}
                           style={{
                               width: 30,
                               height: 30,
                               resizeMode: 'center',
                               position:'relative',
                               marginLeft:5,
                           }}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    })
});
```

This is the code I use to create and put the navigation images

Comment: Are other images that are supposed to be bundled with your app showing correctly or just those from the navigation bar that are failing? I assume the product images come from an external API...

Comment: the problem is only with this pair of images and the 2 are stored in the misca folder where they are all. the strange thing is that in the emulator it looks perfect but it goes up to the store and they are no longer seen